# How to display an ArrayList in a TextView when a Button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am new to android programming and have been watching youtube videos for the past 3 months trying to learn by trial and error. I'm stuck.

All I'm trying to do is display my "JokeList.java" in a TextView (robotJoke) after the Button on the screen is clicked. Can someone please help me?

Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.wdoty.comedianrobot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> jokeList;
TextView robotJoke;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    robotJoke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robotJoke);

}

public void buttonClicked(){
    printJoke();
}

public void printJoke(){
    String jokeString = jokeList.toString();
    robotJoke.setText(jokeString);
}


}
```

Here is my ArrayList.java (JokeList.java)

```
package com.example.wdoty.comedianrobot;
import java.util.*;



public class JokeList extends MainActivity{

public void jokes(){

    ArrayList<String> jokeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    jokeList.add("Why couldn't the bicycle stand up?"+
            "Because it was two tired");
    jokeList.add("What do you call a cheese that isn't yours?"+
            "Nacho Cheese!");
    jokeList.add("Before I criticize a man, I like to walk a mile in his shoes."+
            "That way, when I do criticize him, I'm a mile away and I have his shoes.");
    jokeList.add("What do you call a fish with no eye?"+
            "Fssshh");
    jokeList.add("Have you heard the one about the Corduroy pillow?"+
            "It's making HEADLINES!");
    jokeList.add("What's red and bad for your teeth?"+
            "A brick.");
    jokeList.add("Why didn't the melons get married?"+
            "Because they cantaloupe!");
    jokeList.add("What did the cobbler say when a cat wandered into his shop?"+
            "Shoe!");
    jokeList.add("What did the Buddhist say to the hot dog vendor?"+
            "Make me one with everything!");
    jokeList.add("The face of a child can say it all"+
            "especially the mouth part of the face.");
    jokeList.add("Why did the cookie go to the hospital?"+
            "Because he felt crummy.");
    jokeList.add("I intend to live forever..."+
            "So far, so good.");

}

}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/android"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/robotText"
    android:text="Hello. My name is Andy the Android I like telling jokes. Click the button below if you would like for me to tell you 1."
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@id/robotText"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/robotJoke"
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and buttonClick replace by this
public void buttonClicked(View v){
do whatever you want
}

Comment: Jokelist class is not activity why you extend to MainActivity

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, gimme a moment.

Comment: Why don't you show this arraylist in custom adapter in listview

Comment: That will give you extra functionality when you click on one joke

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over the list and append the elements of the list one by one.

```
public void printJoke(){
    StringBuilder jokeStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : jokeList) {
        jokeStringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
    }
    robotJoke.setText(jokeStringBuilder.toString());
}
```

Another error is that you need to pass the View in `buttonClicked()` function to be `buttonClicked(View v)`

Answer (score 0):

First define textview than take all data from your ArrayList and set the textview like this example

```
TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid);
for (int i=0; i<jokeList.size();i++) {   
   mText.setText(jokeList.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JokeList doesn't need to extends MainActivity.
Add a constructor to fill your array.

```
public class JokeList{
private ArrayList<String> jokeList;
public JokeList(){

    jokeList = new ArrayList<String>();

    jokeList.add("Why couldn't the bicycle stand up?"+
            "Because it was two tired");
    jokeList.add("What do you call a cheese that isn't yours?"+
            "Nacho Cheese!");
    jokeList.add("Before I criticize a man, I like to walk a mile in his shoes."+
            "That way, when I do criticize him, I'm a mile away and I have his shoes.");
    jokeList.add("What do you call a fish with no eye?"+
            "Fssshh");
    jokeList.add("Have you heard the one about the Corduroy pillow?"+
            "It's making HEADLINES!");
    jokeList.add("What's red and bad for your teeth?"+
            "A brick.");
    jokeList.add("Why didn't the melons get married?"+
            "Because they cantaloupe!");
    jokeList.add("What did the cobbler say when a cat wandered into his shop?"+
            "Shoe!");
    jokeList.add("What did the Buddhist say to the hot dog vendor?"+
            "Make me one with everything!");
    jokeList.add("The face of a child can say it all"+
            "especially the mouth part of the face.");
    jokeList.add("Why did the cookie go to the hospital?"+
            "Because he felt crummy.");
    jokeList.add("I intend to live forever..."+
            "So far, so good.");

}
 public ArrayList<String> jokes(){
     return jokeList;
}


}
```

Your activity :
Create a JokeList object and ask him the ArrayList.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> jokeList;
JokeList myJokes;
TextView robotJoke;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    robotJoke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robotJoke);
    myJokes = new JokeList();

}

public void buttonClicked(){
    printJoke();
}

public void printJoke(){
    jokeList = myJokes.jokes();
    String jokeString = jokeList.toString();
    robotJoke.setText(jokeString);
}


}
```

Comment: It doesn't really have to be a class either, it's just a single method.

Comment: Maybe he wants to create others methods later. But yes, if he just need to fill an array, a method in the MainActivity is a better solution.

Comment: "Maybe he wants to create others methods later." - maybe that should be stated in the question, so that the Jokes class need to be extensible. But hey, it's a homework/hobby app :) The man will form an opinion (and taste) on the matter as he gets used to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we're going to do this a bit differently...

```
package com.example.wdoty.comedianrobot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> jokeList;
TextView robotJoke;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    robotJoke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robotJoke);
    jokeList = jokes();
}

public void buttonClicked(){
    printJoke();
}

public void printJoke(){
    Random jokeNumber = new Random();
    String jokeString = jokeList.get(jokeNumber.nextInt() % jokeList.size()).toString();
    robotJoke.setText(jokeString);
}

public ArrayList<String> jokes(){

ArrayList<String> jokeList = new ArrayList<String>();

jokeList.add("Why couldn't the bicycle stand up?"+
        "Because it was two tired");
jokeList.add("What do you call a cheese that isn't yours?"+
        "Nacho Cheese!");
jokeList.add("Before I criticize a man, I like to walk a mile in his shoes."+
        "That way, when I do criticize him, I'm a mile away and I have his shoes.");
jokeList.add("What do you call a fish with no eye?"+
        "Fssshh");
jokeList.add("Have you heard the one about the Corduroy pillow?"+
        "It's making HEADLINES!");
jokeList.add("What's red and bad for your teeth?"+
        "A brick.");
jokeList.add("Why didn't the melons get married?"+
        "Because they cantaloupe!");
jokeList.add("What did the cobbler say when a cat wandered into his shop?"+
        "Shoe!");
jokeList.add("What did the Buddhist say to the hot dog vendor?"+
        "Make me one with everything!");
jokeList.add("The face of a child can say it all"+
        "especially the mouth part of the face.");
jokeList.add("Why did the cookie go to the hospital?"+
        "Because he felt crummy.");
jokeList.add("I intend to live forever..."+
        "So far, so good.");

return jokeList;
}

}
```

Comment: Shark when I used your code, it gives me an error with: "length" (can't resolve method) and return "jokes" (can't resolve symbol jokes). Any ideas?

Comment: did you copy the `jokes()` method from the answer?

Comment: ouch, sorry, just spotted the problem... `jokes()` was returning a non-existant list. Other than that, the `jokeList` initializes in `onCreate()` by using `jokeList = jokes();` so everything else should check out fine.

Comment: Yeah...Just to be sure I copied and pasted your code in my project to make sure i didn't miss anything.

Comment: lemme fix the `length()` issue as well... forgot that ArrayList uses `size()` instead of `length()` :D

Comment: should be better now.

Comment: I the "size" and "length" fix worked...So for the "return jokes()", do I completely remove it?

Comment: copy the code above, `return jokes()` is nowhere to be found, and if you put `return jokes()` in the jokes() method, you'll eventually either run out of memory or hit a stack overflow.

Comment: Code looks good now but when I run the android emulator the app opens then when I click on the button it force closes. Any ideas?

Comment: Post the logcat and I will have ideas, most probably on monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> jokeList;
TextView robotJoke;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    robotJoke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robotJoke);

}

public void buttonClicked(View v){ // Missing View paramter
    printJoke();
}

public void printJoke(){
//from @Ahmed Hegazy
    StringBuilder jokeStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : jokeList) {
        jokeStringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
    }
    robotJoke.setText(jokeStringBuilder.toString());
}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code:

```
package com.example.wdoty.comedianrobot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> jokeList;
TextView robotJoke;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        robotJoke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.robotJoke);    
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view){
        jokes();
        printJoke();
    }

    public void printJoke(){        
        String jokeString = jokeList.toString();
        robotJoke.setText(jokeString);
    }  

    public void jokes(){    
        jokeList = new ArrayList<String>();    
        jokeList.add("Why couldn't the bicycle stand up?"+
                "Because it was two tired");
        jokeList.add("What do you call a cheese that isn't yours?"+
                "Nacho Cheese!");
        jokeList.add("Before I criticize a man, I like to walk a mile in his shoes."+
                "That way, when I do criticize him, I'm a mile away and I have his shoes.");
        jokeList.add("What do you call a fish with no eye?"+
                "Fssshh");
        jokeList.add("Have you heard the one about the Corduroy pillow?"+
                "It's making HEADLINES!");
        jokeList.add("What's red and bad for your teeth?"+
                "A brick.");
        jokeList.add("Why didn't the melons get married?"+
                "Because they cantaloupe!");
        jokeList.add("What did the cobbler say when a cat wandered into his shop?"+
                "Shoe!");
        jokeList.add("What did the Buddhist say to the hot dog vendor?"+
                "Make me one with everything!");
        jokeList.add("The face of a child can say it all"+
                "especially the mouth part of the face.");
        jokeList.add("Why did the cookie go to the hospital?"+
                "Because he felt crummy.");
        jokeList.add("I intend to live forever..."+
                "So far, so good.");
        String jokeString = jokeList.toString();
        Log.d("JOKES",jokeString);    
    }
```

Comment: see answer with open eyes i callled function jokes. in that function arrayList is preparing

Comment: Ah, missed that it's a global variable, my bad. Still, it won't print a single joke - it will be more like `[ "joke1Q? joke1A", "joke2Q? joke2A", "joke3Q? joke3A", ...]` you probably want to get a single random joke out of the list and put that on the textview.

Comment: I don't plan on running your code, I'm not making a joking app. I just said that you may want to pick a single joke instead of printing all of them in a single TextView. It's up to the OP to run it and accept it.